# How do you deal when the implementation for an interface method is the same for some classes?

Tags: java, class, oop, design-patterns, interface

Assume I have defined interface ISomeInterface with methods foo and bar.
E.g.

```
public interface ISomeInterface {  
    public void foo();  
    public void bar();  
}
```

Let's say I have classes A and B that for them it makes sense to both implement the interface. But it also does not make sense to have a different implementation for `foo()`.
Taking into account that deriving A from B or B from A is incorrect/weird is there a standard coding practice for this design?
I assume I could create some utilities class to implement `foo()` and call it as a delegate but I was wondering if this whole structure can be dealt with differently

**Update:**
To give a full understanding of my question I stumbled upon this:http://perlbuzz.com/2010/07/why-roles-in-perl-are-awesome.html and I was trying to understand if this feature is lacking from the traditional OO concepts as we use them in Java or not

Comment: Why don't you make your interface to an abstract class and provide an implmentation for foo()?

Comment: If you're in Java8, you could provide a [default implementation in the interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) or you could always follow the agile manifesto and opt for a has-A relationship by creating a collaborator that can perform the functionality. The A and B would have an is-A relationship with the interface and a has-A relationship with the collaborator.

Comment: @Dan Temple:See update

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to represent multiple inheritance with roles within Java. As pointed out in the article, Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so abstract classes aren't going to help too much here. But you can implement multiple interfaces, which might be useful to give you the *feel* of roles. I wonder if the default methods in Java8 are actually comparative to the default implementation from Perl5 though.

Comment: @DanTemple: My main concern is that to be honest I don't see any need of "Roles". So I was wondering if this is a miss from OO as we use it in Java

Answer (score 4):

Your edit suggests that your true question is: "Is there an equivalent for Perl roles in Java?"

Since Java 8 introduced `default` methods in interfaces, interfaces with default methods seem like a very good equivalent for roles. Especially, you can do what you want in your example: Provide a default implementation for `foo()`:

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    public default void foo(){ /* your default impl goes here */}
    public void bar(); // Abstract, must be implemented by subclasses
}

class A implements ISomeInterface {
    // must only implement bar, can reuse foo's default impl
}

class B implements ISomeInterface {
    // must only implement bar, can reuse foo's default impl
}
```

If there is a feature about roles I am missing please let me know. Otherwise, I think Java8 interfaces are a quite good surrogate for roles.

Comment: You are correct. My main concern is that to be honest I don't see any need of "Roles". So I was wondering if this is a miss from OO as we use it in Java

Comment: @Jim: To be honest, roles seem a lot like usual traits (i.e., interfaces with implementation) to me. The authors that advocate roles as something completely different just try to give them another "look and feel" but in their core, I see no big difference to usual multi inheritance...

Answer (score 1):

Decided to turn my comment into an answer:

You could use an abstract class rather than an interface:

```
    public abstract class FooBar {  
        public void foo(){
       //your implementation goes here  
        }

        abstract void bar();  
    } 

    public class A extends FooBar{

        @Override
        public void bar(){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this :

```
public class abstract SomeAbstractClass {  
    public void foo(){
       //implementation
    }  
    public abstract void bar();  
} 

class A extends SomeAbstractClass {

}

class B extends SomeAbstractClass {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class SomeClass implements ISomeInterface {
    public void foo() {
        // I do stuff..
    }
}

public class A extends SomeClass {
    public void bar() {
        // A specific impl. of bar..
    }
}

public class B extends SomeClass {
    public void bar() {
        // B specific impl. of bar..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't want A and B to be tied up by extending an abstract class you can just use composition. This also provides the flexibility to change the `IFoo` behaviour at run time if you were to inject the `FooImpl` as part of the constructor. In this example I have just hard wired the `FooImpl` for brevity.

```
public class B implements ISomeInterface {

    private IFoo foo = new FooImpl();

    public void foo() {
        foo.doSomethingFooey();
    }

    public void bar() {
        // B specific implementation        
    }
}

public class A implements ISomeInterface {

    private IFoo foo = new FooImpl();

    public void foo() {
        foo.doSomethingFooey();
    }

    public void bar() {
        // A specific implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: You would implement additional interfaces and provide helper classes similar to `IFoo + FooImpl` (shown above) that would contain the implementation for the required behaviour

Comment: Does this mean that this feature is needed and is missing? Because from your suggestion I would need to write a whole new hierarchy of helper classes

Comment: Not missing.Java us a statically typed language, therefore the compiler needs to know that a class supports a method. Implementing an interface is how java expresses this. Creating lots of specific small classes is actually good OO design (think single responsibility principle). Failing that maybe your design would be better suited to a Functional approach